# Attaching global meta to custom fields

Tags: posts, custom-field

I post music videos on my site and I add the artist name as a custom field to each post. I want to associate certain meta with that artist name so I dont have to enter it everytime like the artists twitter account and link to Facebook. So my question is how could I enter in their meta data once somewhere and call it to every post automatically where their artist name is entered for a field. Hope I explained that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way I would tackle this would be a non-hierarchical taxonomy. That would allow you to tag the artist and such as well as give you a few fields to work with for basic data input...you also have the ability to expand, should you need it. If you're going to have a lot of terms and you need additional fields, I think I would store those in a custom table for ease of access and to keep clutter down in wp_options. I can provide pseudo code for any of the above implementation.

Comment: That would be awesome! I'm reading up on what you mean by that now. And I would need other fields in the future but have never created a table. Time to learn.

Comment: Let me know what you'd like to see and I'll draw it up...assuming it's not in depth enough that you feel another question is warranted.

Comment: I just need to tag the artist with their facebook page url, twitter url and personal website. I enter in the artist name as the custom field 'artist_name'. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yea, I can't think of a good way to store that without extending the default storage options or using them in ways that they weren't intended to be used...other than maybe comma separated values in the description. You should be entering the artist's name into the custom taxonomy you register (see: `register_taxonomy()`)

Comment: Hmmm so I would create a taxonomy for each artist and assign it with the artist name and then tag a post with that artist name?

Comment: Nope, create a non-hierarchical taxonomy (maybe call it Artists), it will act like tags do, but be a separate taxonomy. Within this taxonomy, store your artists as terms. You can then register additional custom fields that can be used on `edit-tag.php` specifically for the taxonomy you've created to store additional information about the artist.